# function declaration issue with interface that has static properties

Tags: typescript, constants, let

```
interface IFn {
  (): number
  count: number
}
let fn: IFn = () => {
  return 1
}
fn.count = 0
```

Above code will occur an error:

```
Property 'count' is missing in type '() => number' but required in type 'IFn'.
```

But if I change `let` to `const`, the error disappears:

```
interface IFn {
  (): number
  count: number
}
const fn: IFn = () => {
  return 1
}
fn.count = 0
```

This is very confusing to me. I search a lot but get nothing, can someone help me? Thanks.

---

**SOME UPDATE**

If I define `fn` with `const` without assigning `fn.count`, I will get the same error.

```
interface IFn {
  (): number
  count: number
}
const fn: IFn = () => {
  return 1
}
```

if I assign `fn` with type assertion or `Object.assign()`, the "let" way is ok.

```
interface IFn {
  (): number
  count: number
}
let fn: IFn = (() => 1) as IFn
fn.count = 1

console.log(fn()) // 1
console.log(fn.count) // 1
```

```
interface IFn {
  (): number
  count: number
}
let fn: IFn = Object.assign(() => 1, { count: 1 })

console.log(fn()) // 1
console.log(fn.count) // 1
```

This problem seems to occur only when the interface has a function type definition(not very sure), here's a similar example and it will get an error:

```
interface IOjb {
  a: number
  b: number
}
const obj: IOjb = { a: 1 }
obj.b = 2
```

Comment: why are you writing `const` twice? or `const` and `let` together?

Comment: sorry, I wrote wrong. Now it's right.

Comment: note: the error is not only dependent on `let` or `const`. If you remove `fn.count = 0` the code with `const` will also have the same error