# Function call signature gives error if the function was declared without `const` keyword

Tags: typescript, tsc

I'm new to TypeScript and while learning [Call Signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures), I keep getting error if I store the function with `let` or `const` keyword. Like So:

#### Call signature

```js
type Foo = {
    desc: string,
    (arg: string): void
}
```

#### If I create a function and store it using `let` or `var` keyword,

```js
let bar: Foo = function(arg: string): void{
    console.log(arg);
}
bar.desc = 'baz';
```

#### I get following error:

```
 error TS2741: Property 'desc' is missing in type '(arg: string) => void' but required in type 'Foo'.
```

#### However, if I store the function in a constant variable, it works as expected

```js
type Foo = {
    desc: string,
    (arg: string): void
}

const bar: Foo = function(arg: string): void{
    console.log(arg);
}
bar.desc = 'baz';
```

#### Are there any specific reason behind it? Am I missing something?

Comment: We had the same question here a while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71935053/function-declaration-issue-with-interface-that-has-static-properties. But it never got an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for adding properties to functions was [introduced in TypeScript 3.1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions) as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#26368](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26368).  The feature is documented specifically as:

> Allow JS-container (expando) property assignments in Typescript, but only for function declarations and function/arrow expressions used as initialisers of const variables.

So this is working as intended; `const` variables initialized with functions can have properties added to them, but there is no support for `let` or `var`.

---

Curiously I don't see any authoritative source for exactly *why* `let` and `var` are not supported.  Instead, all I can offer is an educated guess: it is because [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) on `function` statements and `const` variables is *much easier* than it is for `var` or `let` variables.  A `function` statement and a `const` variable cannot be reassigned, so once you know that there is an extra property on the function, that property will continue to exist unless someone modifies the property directly.  On the other hand, a `var` or `let` could be reassigned, meaning that the compiler would need to check to see that this did not happen between the adding of the property and its attempted use, which could be quite complicated depending on scopes.

So, my expectation is that the feature was added to support the simple cases, and that the more complicated cases are not yet supported because there hasn't been much demand for them, if any.  If you have some important use case for it (some reason why `const` is insufficient), you might want to file a feature request.